# How to replace all the whitepaces with '-' in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The data I have, as below

Client ID:16402600010001                          Merchant ID:372048655883                          Terminal ID:7582626                               07/08/16                                  20:51:12                       SALE                                         Invoice:106393                  Account:DEBIT ************8747                    Cardholder:ZAMOA/ KAANDRA                      Card Entry Mode:Swiped                            Result:CAPTURED                                   Authorization Code:971125                         CTroutd:11118                                     Approved Amount:2.64                              Subtotal:                                     2.64Total:                                        2.64

There is 4-5 tabs and whites spaces between each string. Now, I want to replace all the white spaces with `-` (dash). What will be regular expression for that?

Comment: Are these separate columns or is this data all in one column? Some formatting and a table structure might help, as it's not very clear what your "data" represents.

Comment: This entire data is in one single row. Yes, there is whites spaces or tabs or new lines in between of like ClientID, Merchant ID, TerminalID, date and so on

Comment: Can you just use a simple REPLACE, e.g. SELECT REPLACE(<column_name>, ' ', '-') FROM <table_name>; ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(column_name, '\\s+', ' ')) as mystring FROM Table_name;
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.